# Removing RTK Correction from Images

Tags: georeferencing, unmanned-aerial-vehicle, agisoft-photoscan, rtkgps+, dji

I am doing a thesis research and I was supposed to analyze an un-corrected dataset (drone images collected only using GNSS).

When I load the images into Agisoft Metashape (professional version 1.8.4 build 14856 (64 bit)), the accuracy reports the images have been corrected using RTK. In this case, the DJI D-RTK 2 Mobile Station was used.

Is there a way to remove RTK correction from the images and have them un-corrected or with GNSS only?

10 images from dataset can be found at [raw images](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AoudchX_DjaDh_JI_0SW5IwZAhNhMg?e=aVCN7T).

GDAL command:

```
gdalinfo "/Raw Images/100_0001_0009.JPG"
GDAL command output:
Driver: JPEG/JPEG JFIF 
Files: /Raw Images/100_0001_0009.JPG 
Size is 5472, 3648 
Metadata: 
EXIF_ApertureValue=(4.97) 
EXIF_BodySerialNumber=37d926670214d01cf763d6b9f32edc3a 
EXIF_ColorSpace=1 
EXIF_ComponentsConfiguration=0x00 0x03 0x02 0x01 
EXIF_CompressedBitsPerPixel=(3.36722) 
EXIF_Contrast=0 
EXIF_CustomRendered=0 
EXIF_DateTime=2022:06:16 09:14:11 
EXIF_DateTimeDigitized=2022:06:16 09:14:10 
EXIF_DateTimeOriginal=2022:06:16 09:14:10 
EXIF_DigitalZoomRatio=(0) 
EXIF_ExifVersion=0230 
EXIF_ExposureBiasValue=(0) 
EXIF_ExposureIndex=(0) 
EXIF_ExposureMode=0 
EXIF_ExposureProgram=2 
EXIF_ExposureTime=(0.002) 
EXIF_FileSource=0x03 
EXIF_Flash=32 
EXIF_FlashpixVersion=0010 
EXIF_FNumber=(5.6) 
EXIF_FocalLength=(8.8) 
EXIF_FocalLengthIn35mmFilm=24 
EXIF_GainControl=0 
EXIF_GPSAltitude=(12.136) 
EXIF_GPSAltitudeRef=0x00 
EXIF_GPSLatitude=(27) (46) (58.2821) 
EXIF_GPSLatitudeRef=N 
EXIF_GPSLongitude=(97) (33) (41.0364) 
EXIF_GPSLongitudeRef=W 
EXIF_GPSVersionID=0x02 0x03 0x00 0x00 
EXIF_ImageDescription=DCIM\SURVEY\100_0001\100_0 
EXIF_Interoperability_Index=R98 
EXIF_Interoperability_Version=0x30 0x31 0x30 0x30 
EXIF_ISOSpeedRatings=100 
EXIF_LightSource=1 
EXIF_Make=DJI 
EXIF_MakerNote=$ 
EXIF_MaxApertureValue=(2.97) 
EXIF_MeteringMode=1 
EXIF_Model=FC6310R 
EXIF_Orientation=1 
EXIF_PixelXDimension=5472 
EXIF_PixelYDimension=3648 
EXIF_ResolutionUnit=2 
EXIF_Saturation=0 
EXIF_SceneCaptureType=0 
EXIF_SceneType=0x01 
EXIF_Sharpness=0 
EXIF_ShutterSpeedValue=(8.965) 
EXIF_Software=v01.09.1759 
EXIF_SubjectDistance=(0) 
EXIF_SubjectDistanceRange=0 
EXIF_WhiteBalance=1 
EXIF_XResolution=(72) 
EXIF_YCbCrPositioning=1 
EXIF_YResolution=(72) 
Image Structure Metadata: 
COMPRESSION=JPEG 
INTERLEAVE=PIXEL 
SOURCE_COLOR_SPACE=YCbCr 
Corner Coordinates: 
Upper Left ( 0.0, 0.0) 
Lower Left ( 0.0, 3648.0) 
Upper Right ( 5472.0, 0.0) 
Lower Right ( 5472.0, 3648.0) 
Center ( 2736.0, 1824.0) 
Band 1 Block=5472x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Red 
Overviews: 2736x1824, 1368x912, 684x456, 160x120 
Image Structure Metadata: 
COMPRESSION=JPEG 
Band 2 Block=5472x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Green 
Overviews: 2736x1824, 1368x912, 684x456, 160x120 
Image Structure Metadata: 
COMPRESSION=JPEG 
Band 3 Block=5472x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Blue 
Overviews: 2736x1824, 1368x912, 684x456, 160x120 
Image Structure Metadata: 
COMPRESSION=JPEG
```

Allegedly collected using DJI D-RTK 2:
[image: DJI D-RTK 2]

Collected using only GNSS:
[image: GNSS]

Comment: Run an image through EXIFTools or use a gdalinfo command to view the EXIF data.  Post the results of that inquiry to your question.  Maybe both values are written to the EXIF/XMP tags?  If so, you could use Python tools to create a new set of images with the uncorrected lats/longs to the EXIF tags.  Can you make a small group of the images available for download?

Comment: Also, maybe the data you need can be found in the flight logs?  https://www.phantomhelp.com/logviewer/upload/

Comment: I have downloaded your images and ran them through Agisoft Metashape.  I have also looked at your EXIF data with EXIF tools.  I do not see any reference in these images that specify RTK values.  Agisoft is returning an accuracy of 10m for each image.   In the old days of drone photogrammetry (a few years ago) the RTK unit for a Matrice would not write the RTK values to the images, RTK was only used for navigation and the consumer-grade GNSS was still being written to the EXIF. Can add more information and confirm RTK to the EXIF?  Screenshots from Agisoft maybe? Detail your workflow?

Comment: @GBG I just uploaded them into Agisoft and I could see the accuracy. No further process was performed.

Comment: These are values that you are getting in Agisoft after you add GCPs and mark the images with the GCPs locations?

Comment: No, I have not aligned images, nor have I uploaded GCPs. I have only uploaded the images.

Comment: Odd that I would see a different accuracy.  I have no further advice.